# Oracle APEX is it possible to change the calendar month when changing the month on a page item?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

because I'm new to this and my JS knowledge is limited,

I have P_2135_MONTH (which contains a select list of all months 01-12).

Calendar always loads on current month e.g. September 2023

is it possible to change the calendar month when changing the month on a page item?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jariola answer this question in Oracle forums and i want to share the correct answer here.
"Go edit your calendar region. Find attribute static id. Enter some string to that field and use that same string in JavaScript like this:

Create dynamic action that executes JavaScript when item changes

`var lMonth = "2023-" + this.triggeringElement.value + "-01"; apex.region("<region static id here>").widget().data("fullCalendar").gotoDate(lMonth);`"

Thank you very much jariola